# How to trigger and handle form submission in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to trigger a form submit and handle it using jquery. Below is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form>
        <input value="hello" name="check">
        <input type="submit" value="abc">
    </form>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("form").trigger("submit", (event) => {
        console.log(event)
        event.preventDefault();
    })
</script>

</html>
```

However, when I run this code, my form submits in an infinite loop. I was expecting the console to print the event object and stop submission from happening. What is wrong in my code and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) call doesn't take a function for its second argument, so you can't use `preventDeafult` in that way, unfortunately. The second argument for `trigger` takes in extra parameters which will be passed onto the handler.

You can, however, write another bit of code to intercept the form submission:

```js
// this code handles the event from the form submission
$('form').submit(e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Within submit');
});

// this codes triggers the form submission
$("form").trigger("submit")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input value="hello" name="check">
    <input type="submit" value="abc">
</form>
```

---

To expand on how the second argument to `trigger` works, here's an example which shows the arguments which have been passed into the `submit` function. You can see that each item of the array passed to `trigger` has been passed as an argument to `submit`, as well as the actual event.

```js
// this code handles the event from the form submission
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Within submit');
  console.dir(arguments);
});

// this codes triggers the form submission
$("form").trigger("submit", ['more', 'arguments', 'for', 'submit'])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input value="hello" name="check">
    <input type="submit" value="abc">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `submit()` function triggers when a user tries to submit a form. jQuery submit form method attaches a handler, which executes when the submit event is fired.

The syntax for submit form using jQuery `submit()` function:

[jQuery .submit() API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

[jQuery .submit() simple example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_submit.asp)

This signature is used without any arguments. This method is a shortcut for `.trigger( "submit" )`.

It is used as `(DOM_OBJECT).submit(handler)`

Where the handler is a function, which is executed when the form is submitted. This method is a shortcut for `.on( "submit", handler )`.

Following example demonstrates `submit()` function usage for form submission using jQuery.

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
$("span").text("Submitted Successfully...").show();
event.preventDefault();
});
```

You may have noticed `event.preventDefault()` in the above code. You will see an alert, if you try the above example after removing this line. We used `alert()` method as the default action. So the `event.preventDefault()` is required in the code to prevent this default action.